# SVGs looking different on different devices

Tags: svg

My SVG looks different on different platforms. Why so?
Examples-

On my laptop

[image: On my Laptop]

On my mobile(text running out of box):
[image: on mobile]

Not just text running out of boxes, also arrow positions shift a bit. I make them using diagrams.net if it matters.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="294px" height="93px" viewBox="-0.5 -0.5 294 93" content="&lt;mxfile host=&quot;app.diagrams.net&quot; modified=&quot;2021-06-15T10:21:25.327Z&quot; agent=&quot;5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.101 Safari/537.36 Edg/91.0.864.48&quot; etag=&quot;-FsMRlwHQoiKKWVryYAU&quot; version=&quot;14.7.7&quot; type=&quot;device&quot;&gt;&lt;diagram id=&quot;LL04G3attlTuYx5v-QkI&quot; name=&quot;Page-1&quot;&gt;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&lt;/diagram&gt;&lt;/mxfile&gt;"><defs/><g><rect x="1" y="1" width="289.24" height="87.5" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" pointer-events="all" transform="translate(2,3)" opacity="0.25"/><rect x="1" y="1" width="289.24" height="87.5" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#7ea6e0" stroke-width="2" pointer-events="all"/><g transform="translate(-0.5 -0.5)"><switch><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 287px; height: 1px; padding-top: 45px; margin-left: 2px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; "><font><font style="font-size: 16px">http GET Request</font><br /></font><div style="background-color: rgb(255 , 255 , 255) ; font-family: &quot;consolas&quot; , &quot;courier new&quot; , monospace ; line-height: 22px ; font-size: 14px"><div style="font-family: &quot;consolas&quot; , &quot;courier new&quot; , monospace ; line-height: 22px"><span style="color: #a31515">"https://www.dart.dev/tutorials/web/</span></div><div style="font-family: &quot;consolas&quot; , &quot;courier new&quot; , monospace ; line-height: 22px"><span style="color: #a31515">fetch-data"</span></div></div></div></div></div></foreignObject><text x="146" y="48" fill="#000000" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="12px" text-anchor="middle">http GET Request...</text></switch></g></g><switch><g requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"/><a transform="translate(0,-5)" xlink:href="https://www.diagrams.net/doc/faq/svg-export-text-problems" target="_blank"><text text-anchor="middle" font-size="10px" x="50%" y="100%">Viewer does not support full SVG 1.1</text></a></switch></svg>
```

What should I do to make sure it looks uniform everywhere?

Comment: perhaps the mobile devices don't have the fonts you've specified.

Comment: It happens not only on mobile device; I sent it to a friend of mine, it looked different on his too

Comment: some devices have some fonts, some don't. You need to pick fonts that are widely distributed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @robert-longson said in the comments, using more widely distributed and web safe fonts like Arial, Helvetica, etc solved the issue.